# Opening more in "Notepad++"

Tags: notepad++, encoding, plugins, file-types

After combing over the forum to make sure the question wasn't asked by someone else first I'm guessing I may be the only one to have asked this...

Is there a way to increase the file types that Notepad++ is able to open and understand?

[A familiar face?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCvcC.png)

I know this happens when Notepad++ doesn't understand the method in which the file is formatted.  Hence my interest in whether or not there is plug-ins anywhere that extend the files that it can handle.

Comment: Notepad++ *understands* the file, but it is a binary file so **you** cannot understand it.

Comment: Hm, I do understand as much.  But I was more looking for an plug-in that makes the data something more mundane that I'd be able to work with.  Y'know?

Comment: What's the extension? You're not going to be able to open a .JPEG image in N++ and see a picture...

Comment: I know it can't be used to open graphic files.  I'm trying to open what should be text files.  I was generally looking for extended tags it could handle to avoid parsing in random gibberish like that.  Anyway, this file was an *.sts file.